# Display Table of contents of the map in ArcMap in the online published Map/Web map application

Tags: arcgis-10.1, table

The following is the sample layer information of the map in ArcMap 10.1:
[image]

How can I have the same Table of contents in the published map online or in web map application, so that user can select/unselect layer's content?

Is there any feature I need to enable to have all contents appear for online user?
Do I need to implement JavaScript API?Is there any sample available?

Thanks

Comment: how are you planning on making it appear online? Assuming you have ArcServer. Which API Are you using? Are you using ArcGIS Online? We need more information on what you plan on using before we can offer good suggestions.

Comment: I want the to appear like the "Edit" template of arcgis online.I would like you to create a web page where a user can select the layers  with a pull down menu  and then be able to check boxes in order to select what layer to see.